# ASP.NET Core 2.0: HTTP requests timeout, but HTTPS requests doesn't

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, asp.net-core, https

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC app that works perfectly fine when requesting it over HTTPS. E.g. `https://localhost:44331` or `https://example.com`

However, if you attempt to access it over HTTP, it fails with a timeout. Both when run locally and when deployed to the production server (IIS 8).

I figured I just had to set up HTTP to HTTPS redirection and thus added the following code to the `Configure` method in `Startup.cs`:

```
RewriteOptions options = new RewriteOptions().AddRedirectToHttps(StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently);
app.UseRewriter(options);
```

But it has no effect. The HTTP requests still timeout, while the HTTPS ones do not.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do, is to make it so that users don't have to type `https://example.com` to access the site. Instead, I want it to be possible for the users to just type `example.com` and then be redirected to `https://example.com`.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this issue for almost a day now, so any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain the http server is listening? If you do telnet example.com 80, does it connect or timeout?

Comment: @TerryCarmen ...You have no idea how stupid I feel right now. Turns out port 80 was being directed to an old server, rather than the web server. If you post the comment as an answer, I'll gladly mark it solved. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy to help! Don't feel stupid. I've been doing this for 30+ years and these types of things still bite me now and then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The http server might not be listening. 
Since you did a telnet example.com 80, and it didn't connect then there is your problem.

Comment: This should be posted as an comment, not as an answer. You should rephrase it as an answer based on the comments